# Fancybox 3: Disable zoom when image is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-3

I have set up a simple image slider using the Fancybox 3 plugin (http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/) within the Kirby CMS (https://getkirby.com/). The only thing I'm not able to work out, is how to stop the slider from zooming into an image when the image is clicked on while the slider is open.

Can someone give me a hand with this?

I tried including `clickSlide : 'close',` in the options for the slider, but it did not work.

Here are the options I have set up for the slider globally on my site:

```
  <!-- Setting fancybox-options GLOBALLY -->

    <script type="text/javascript">

       $("[data-fancybox]").fancybox({

         thumbs          : false,

         hash            : false,

         loop            : true,

         keyboard        : true,

         toolbar         : false,

         animationEffect : false,

         arrows          : true,

       });

    </script>

  <!-- /////////////////////// -->
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use `clickContent` option:

```
$("[data-fancybox]").fancybox({
  thumbs          : false,
  hash            : false,
  loop            : true,
  keyboard        : true,
  toolbar         : false,
  animationEffect : false,
  arrows          : true,
  clickContent    : false
});
```

Demo - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XaabLJ?editors=1010

`clickSlide` option is used for clicks outside content, but inside the slide. And since parent of the slide can be resized (like in this example - https://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/ZKqaKO), `clickOutside` option is when clicked outside the slide.

Answer (score 1):

To disable **click to scroll** and remove zoom button from the toolbar:

```js
$('[data-fancybox]').fancybox({
  clickContent: 'close',
  buttons: ['close']
})
```