# Disable pinch zoom on fancybox images for mobile

Tags: jquery, fancybox-3

I'm currently using [Fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/) I'd like to disable image zoom with the pinch gesture on iPad.

I've tried using CSS `touch-action:none;` and setting options in fancy box.

```
$("[data-fancybox]").fancybox({
  clickContent    : false,
});
```

I'd like the image to not respond to pinch zooming.

Comment: This might be a duplicate of [Fancybox 3: Disable zoom when image is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45638608/fancybox-3-disable-zoom-when-image-is-clicked)

Comment: I tried this - it seemed to address clicks, but not pinch gestures.

Comment: I should mention the I tried:

$("[data-fancybox]").fancybox({
    touch: false
});

and

data-options='{"touch" : false}'

and they did not work for me - I could still pinch and zoom the image

Comment: It works, I can guarantee; if it does not work for you, then you have made some mistake, you have to show your page to see where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable gestures by setting `touch: false`, for example, this would disable for entire page:

`$.fancybox.defaults.touch = false;`

Or you can disable individually by adding`data-options='{"touch" : false}'` to your link.